# Hex of filesize

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, dd

I am following a tutorial on few kernel dev. I encountered an operation where I have to use `dd` like

```
dd ... if=PBL.bin of=... count=block_number
```

The `block_number` variable is defined to be as

```
The HEX of ($filesize - 1)/512 + 1
```

where `$filesize` is the filesize of the input file `PBL.bin` as given in the `dd` command above.

How do I calculate this value? Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `dd` also accepts decimal for `count=` as well. Also please include a link to the tutorial so we can see were this occurs.

Comment: Make sure that you use _signed_ integer arithmetic with that formula.  (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
printf "%x" `stat -c "%b" PBL.bin`
```

printf will print in hex format (%x) the output from stat which requests just the number of blocks allocated (%b) of the file.

If you don't trust the number of blocks allocated as reported by stat then by hand:

```
printf "%x" $(( (`stat -c "%s" PBL.bin ` - 1) / 512 + 1))
```

So you get the filesize and then do the maths by hand

Answer (score 1):

I second the fact that `dd` accepts `count` as decimal. Anyhow here's the Perl way to get what you're asking:

```
perl -e 'printf ("%x\n", -s "PBL.bin")'
```